# check if elements of one ArrayList are present in other

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I have two arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> a1
ArrayList<String> a2
```

I want to check if all the elements of a1 are present in a2.
this is what I was trying which I got from a question on SO

```
if (Arrays.asList(a2).containsAll(Arrays.asList(a1)))
{a2ContainsA1=true;}
```

which is not giving consistent results...is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: What should happen if you have list 1 containing `a, a, b` and list 2 containing `a, b, b`? This makes quite a difference.

Comment: In what way are the results inconsistent?

Comment: Could you include a complete runnable example with an explanation of what you expect to happen and what actually happens?

Comment: `Arrays.asList(a2)` should return a list with one element.

Comment: Have you investigated that the objects stored in the arrays correctly implement equals() ?

Comment: @AlessandroSantini Considering that the objects in the ArrayList are `String` (A built-in Java type) they already have well defined `equals()` methods.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen good point - detail that slipped from my attention.

Comment: @fge as you said list1 with a,a,b and list2 with a,b,b,,,,,then yes it should return true, because all the elements of list1 are there in a2...and more thing, there are no duplicate elemnts in list2, but there is possibility that list1 might contain duplicates...

Comment: @vikasdevde then just use `a1.containsAll(a2)` ;)

Comment: @vikasdevde see also my answer on why your current code does not work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, why are you using `Arrays.asList()` ?

Tried this:

```
    ArrayList<String> a1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> a2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    a1.add("a");
    a1.add("b");
    a2.add("b");
    a2.add("a");

    System.out.println(a2.containsAll(a1));
```

And it outputs `true`
Adding an additional element to `a1` will fail it (as expected):

```
     ArrayList<String> a1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> a2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    a1.add("a");
    a1.add("b");
    a1.add("c");
    a2.add("b");
    a2.add("a");

    System.out.println(a2.containsAll(a1));
```

And it outputs `false`

Comment: What about multiplicity? To me this answer does not seem complete.

Comment: @AlessandroSantini: the question doesn't describe the problem fully. This question is probably the answer, and to me, there's no point in providing every possible solution to a non-clear problem. The OP should define his requirements clearly.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be easier to convert the two ArrayLists to Set objects then use set operations to determine if one is a subset of another. This will also satisfy @fge's comment about duplicity:

```
ArrayList<String> a1 = ...;
ArrayList<String> a2 = ...;

public boolean isSubset(ArrayList<String> a1, ArrayList<String> a2) {
   Set<String> s1 = new HashSet(a1);
   Set<String> s2 = new HashSet(a2);

   return s1.containsAll(s2);
}
```

Comment: You could just `s1.removeAll(a2)` and test if s1 is empty afterwards. And I do suspect this is what the OP means, but he didn't tell, so...

Comment: @fge Yeah, there are several ways that you could do this. I was just going to present one, but I guess it would be good to mention others.

Comment: It is not clear whether duplicates are allowed and whether that matters.

Comment: That is not correct. If the two arrays are supposed to hold duplicates, A2 is a subset of A1 if it contains only elements of A1 and with the same multiplicity.

Comment: Peter Lawrey - if they are not supposed to hold duplicates, he is using the wrong data structure (should be using Sets)

Comment: @AlessandroSantini well, precisely, that is probably the point here: does the OP want to find _unique_ elements in his list. If, and only if, yes, then yes, he should use sets. But at the moment we don't know.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I was just telling that because it avoids creating another set ;)

Answer (score 2):

You already have your lists `a1` and `a2` here, and what you want is to tell whether all unique elements in `a1` are also in `a2`. Therefore you just need to test for:

```
a1.containsAll(a2)
```

`Arrays.asList()` will build a list out of all elements you give as arguments (even if that "all elements" is only one element). In fact, your current code tries to see whether a single-element list which contains the *list object* `a1` contains all elements in another single-element list containing the *list object* `a2`. And this is true if and only if lists `a1` and `a2` are equal, that is, if both of these lists contain the same elements at the same index, as per the `List` contract.

Which is certainly not what you were looking for!

Comment: last line of your answer is true and I have observed while using asList() method... +1 for clearing the concept

Answer (score 1):

you can loop through one of the arrays and do contains on each element therein

```
boolean a2ContainsA1 = true;
for(String str: a2){
    if(!a1.contains(str)){
      a2ContainsA1 = false;
}
```

Comment: This should be fully equivalent to what the OP already tried.

Comment: Yes, but complexity is n*m !

Comment: @vikasdevde please answer my question in the comments right behind your question. If the answer is "yes" then you should go with HunterMcMillen's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should try (assuming you don't want to keep a1 around, or else clone it)

```
boolean conditionVerified = a1.removeAll(a2).isEmpty();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use method `isEqualList()` of [ListUtils](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/ListUtils.html#isEqualList%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29) like -

```
ArrayList<String> a1 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> a2 = new ArrayList<String>();

boolean isEqual = ListUtils.isEqualList(a1,a2);
```

Comment: Actually, after a lof ot talkabout, it appears that the `.containsAll()` method of `Collection` was enough :p

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean contains = true;
for(int i=0 ; i<a1.size() ; i++)
{
  if(!a2.contains(a1[i])
      contains = false;
}
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

disjoint seems to be a good candidate here..

```
check if disjoint using !Collections.disjoint(list1, list2);
```

basic example at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/collections_disjoint.htm